# (SwiftUI Charts/ VisionOS) Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Chart' conform to 'View'

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts, xcode15, visionos

Trying to create a Chart in ContentView. I keep seeing this error no matter how I try to construct it.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct StockView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
              BarMark(
                 x: .value("Department", "Finance"),
                 y: .value("Profit", 300000)
              )
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    StockView()
}
```

> Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Chart' conform to
> 'View'

Comment: Did you import Charts?

Comment: Yes I added `import Charts`

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the full error messages you get and on which line of the code.

Comment: Do you have a custom type named Chart, otherwise follow the advice in the comment above.

Comment: It looks like you haven't put the chart into a view class. Look at the example answer below on how to show this

Comment: It’s a typo, comment out code until you find it

Comment: Updated my code example to provide more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experiment minimum iOS16 or visionOS beta 1 and this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Department", "Finance"),
                y: .value("Profit", 300000)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

compile and run.

[image: chart on Vision Pro Preview]
[image: chart on iPhone simulator]

Comment: I am testing this in VisionOS

Comment: This is valid code for visionOS as well. I suspect you have another struct/class named Chart somewhere which is conflicting with the imported Charts library definition.

Comment: It is working now, thanks. I created a new project and it solved the issue